# Django - Passing a variable from Class Based Views to Template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

In a function based view I can pass on a variable like so:

```
def zip(request):

    check_for_zipcode = request.user.profile.location

    zipcodes = {
        'check_for_zipcode' : check_for_zipcode
    }
    return render(request, 'front/post_form.html',  zipcodes)
```

Then I'll be able to access `check_for_zipcode` in my HTML. But how would I do that in a class based view? Let's say I have the following class based view.

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content', 'post_image', 'title2', 'content2', 'post_image2']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

How would I pass on `check_for_zipcode = request.user.profile.location` in to that class based view?

Answer (score 1):

you can edit the context data in the get_context_data method.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    check_for_zipcode = self.request.user.profile.location
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['zipcodes'] = {'check_for_zipcode' : check_for_zipcode}
    return context
```

now you can access the variable in your html as before